# How to uninstall a package in AI platform JupyterLab notebook?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I want to uninstall a package from an AI platform notebook

```
!pip3 uninstall statsmodels
```

However, I get this response and cannot reply y/n

```
found existing installation: statsmodels 0.11.1
Uninstalling statsmodels-0.11.1:
  Would remove:
    /home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels-0.11.1.dist-info/*
    /home/jupyter/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/*
Proceed (y/n)?
```

I could try to do it from terminal, but I notice what I do in terminal isn't the same as within the notebook. Like if I run pip freeze, I get a different set of packages installed from notebook vs terminal

Comment: !pip3 uninstall statsmodels -y

Comment: I think the difference of behavior between notebook and terminal is due to different versions of python. If you run the command `pip ...` from terminal, it will use the default version (Python 2). If you run the command from the notebook with a Python3 kernel, it will use that version of Python. You can use `pip3 ...` from terminal.

Comment: i see, thanks matteo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like on the command line, you can pass in the answer in advance:

```
!echo y | pip3 uninstall statsmodels
```